# How to get all pixels in mask in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

In python, we can use such code to fetch all pixels under mask:

```
src_img = cv2.imread("xxx")
mask = src_img > 50
fetch = src_img[mask]
```

what we get is a ndarray including all pixels matching condition mask. How to implement the same function using C++opencv ?

I've found that `copyTo` can select pixels under specified mask, but it can only copy those pixels to another `Mat` instead of what python did.

Comment: You're going to need to narrow this down a *lot* more in terms of scope.

Comment: Since you have access to the pixel values, all you have to do is implement the process you want.

Comment: I thought I'd suggest this as a feature to OpenCV: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22847

Answer (score 2):

This is not that straightforward in `C++` (as expected). That operation breaks down in further, smaller operations. One way to achieve a `std::vector` with the same pixel values above your threshold is this, I'm using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBrhW.png) test image:

```
// Read the input image:
std::string imageName = "D://opencvImages//grayDog.png";
cv::Mat inputImage =  cv::imread( imageName );

// Convert BGR to Gray:
cv::Mat grayImage;
cv::cvtColor( inputImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY );

cv::Mat mask;
int thresholdValue = 50;
cv::threshold( grayImage, mask, thresholdValue, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
```

The above bit just creates a `cv::Mat` where each pixel above the threshold is drawn with a value of `255`, `0` otherwise. It is (one possible) equivalent of `mask = src_img > 50`. Now, let's mask the original grayscale image with this mask. Think about an element-wise multiplication between the two `cv::Mat`s. One possible way is this:

```
// Create grayscale mask:
cv::Mat output;
grayImage.copyTo( output, mask );
```

Now we have the original pixel values and everything else is zero. Convenient, because we can find now the locations of the non-zero pixels:

```
// Locate the non-zero pixel values:
std::vector< cv::Point > pixelLocations;
cv::findNonZero( output, pixelLocations );
```

Alright, we have a `std::vector` of `cv::Point`s that locate each non-zero pixel. We can use this info to index the original grayscale pixels in the original matrix:

```
// Extract each pixel value using its location:
std::vector< int > pixelValues;
int totalPoints = (int)pixelLocations.size();

for( int i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++ ){
    // Get pixel location:
    cv::Point currentPoint = pixelLocations[i];

    // Get pixel value:
    int currentPixel = (int)grayImage.at<uchar>( currentPoint );
    pixelValues.push_back( currentPixel );

    // Print info:
    std::cout<<"i: "<<i<<" currentPoint: "<<currentPoint<<" pixelValue: "<<currentPixel<<std::endl;
}
```

You end up with `pixelValues`, which is a `std::vector` containing a list of all the pixels that are above your threshold.

Comment: other possible approach: popcount the mask and initialize result, then run over mask again, and at each true element, figure out index in image and copy element. -- potentially parallelizable if the popcount calculates per-row counts. then the code knows where to place elements for any row. (I'm not inclined to develop the code for that right now :P)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you hate writing loop?

I think this is the easiest way:

```cpp
cv::Mat Img = ... //Where, this Img is 8UC1

// * In this sample, extract the pixel positions
std::vector< cv::Point > ResultData;

const unsigned char Thresh = 50;
for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
{
    const unsigned char *p = Img.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
    for( int x=0; x<Img.cols; ++x, ++p )
    {
        if( *p > Thresh )
        {//Here, pick up this pixel's info you want.
            ResultData.emplace_back( x,y );
        }
    }
}
```

---

Because I received a nervous complaint, I add an example of collecting **values**.

In the following example, a mask image `Mask` is input to the process.

```
cv::Mat Img = ... //Where, this Img is 8UC1
cv::Mat Mask = ...; //Same size as Img, 8UC1

std::vector< unsigned char > ResultData;  //collect pixel values
for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
{
    const unsigned char *p = Img.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
    const unsigned char *m = Mask.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
    for( int x=0; x<Img.cols; ++x, ++p, ++m )
    {
        if( *m ){   ResultData.push_back( *p ); }
    }
}
```

Comment: you collected pixel **coordinates**. OP's python code collected the pixel **values**. -- there's already an answer presenting the necessary code (loop). consider what value another answer can or can't add.

Comment: Another answers have several circuitous steps before the "loop". I think all those steps are unnecessary and what is really needed is simply write a "loop".

Comment: I explicitly said `In this sample, extract the pixel positions` abd `Here, pick up this pixel's info you want` in code.
It's a trivial matter what the code presented as a processing example collects.

Comment: Added the **values** version example. (How to make the `Mask` is omitted, because it is already shown.)